# datetime format does not match with content

Tags: python, datetime

I have checked quite a lot of questions related to this topic but I'm not able to find my error.

My code can be simplified to:

```
date = "2016/07/20"
time = "11:44:20.920"

date_time = datetime.strptime(date + " " + time, '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adma_shortener.py", line 50, in <module>
    adma_time[ii] = datetime.strptime(a, '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f').replace(microsecond=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2016/07/20 11:44:20.920' does not match format '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Can someone see my error? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The year directive should be in caps:

```
date_time = datetime.strptime(date + " " + time, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
#                                                  ^
```

> `%y`  Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number
>
> `%Y`  Year with century as a decimal number.

---

Reference:

http://strftime.org/

Answer (score 2):

`%y` is the specifier for "Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.", which means a two-digit number. Use `%Y` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not very familiar with the [datetime directives](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime), I will suggest you to use [`dateutil.parser`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) instead. It is much simpler. For example:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> date = "2016/07/20"
>>> time = "11:44:20.920"
>>> my_date = dateutil.parser.parse('{date} {time}'.format(date=date, time=time))
>>> my_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 20, 11, 44, 20, 920000)
```

Comment: This is not particularly good advice. If the format of the date is known, you should absolutely use `strptime`, as it is much, MUCH faster and because the parser may erroneously match on malformed date inputs.